If $GL_n(R)$ is bounded, is $GL_{n+1}(R)$ also bounded?
Call a group bounded if the orders of all of its finite subgroups are uniformly bounded by a constant.
For example, the groups $GL_n(\mathbf{Z})$ and $GL_n(\mathbf{Q})$ are bounded (this is classical), on the other hand, $GL_n(\mathbf{C})$ is not bounded for any $n$ as $\mathbf{C}$ contains all $n$th roots of unity.
Now let $R$ be a ring. It is clear that boundedness of $GL_{n+1}(R)$ implies that of $GL_n(R)$ as the latter is a subgroup of the former. I was wondering whether it is possible to find a ring $R$ such that $GL_n(R)$ is bounded for some $n$, but $GL_{n+1}(R)$ is not.

For example, in the group $GL_1(\mathbb{R})$ there is only one nontrivial finite subgroup, and in the group $GL_2(\mathbb{R})$ the orders of finite subgroups are unbounded.  Or did you mean something else?

@kabenyuk thank you for your comment, this is indeed what I was looking for. I'll be happy with any other examples where $n>1$.
